# Ionic 2 chat page same values are repeated

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic 2

Here is my template code

```
 <div class="messagesholder" *ngFor="let chat of chatval | orderby:'[date]'; let last = last">
           {{last ? callFunction() : ''}}  

         <div *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser">
                   <p *ngIf="msgdate === undefined"  class="chat-date" #ChatDate id="ChatDate" >{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p>
                   {{checkdate(chat.date)}}
         </div> 

         <div class="message" *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser" [ngClass]="{'me': currentuser == chat.sender}">
                <div class='image' *ngIf="chat.path" >
                  <img *ngIf="chat.path" [src]="chat.path" imageViewer/><br>
                  <span *ngIf="chat.path_text">{{chat.path_text}}</span>
                  <span style="font-size:9px;">{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'hh:mmA'}}</span>
                </div> 
                 <div *ngIf="chat.message_text">
                 <span>{{chat.message_text}}</span>
                 <span style="font-size:9px;">{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'hh:mmA'}}</span>
                 </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Here is my function

```
checkdate(i)
  {
    console.log("date");
    console.log(i);
    this.msgdate=i;
  }
```

I need same date values are dont repeated.Because i get input element value using this function {{checkdate(chat.date)}}.

But i am getting this err.

```
Error in ./ChatPage class ChatPage - caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

How can i fix this issue...

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting below error because you are trying to modify object which performing back-end process in loop statement.

```
Error in ./ChatPage class ChatPage - caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

If you wants to get unique date then you can try as below example, it will give you unique chatDate from your collection:

```
let Values = this.chatval.map(function (item) { return item["date"]; }).filter(this.OnlyUnique);

OnlyUnique(value, index, self): any {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I have one doubt.I used this function how can i display unique date values in ngfor

Comment: you can use "Values" variable in for statement like *ngFor="let item of Values"